# Installing Python packages/modules on Mac

Tags: python, installation, package

I aim to install scipy and numpy on Python 2.7. My computer is a Mac version OSX 10.8.5. It is the first time I try to install a package on Python.

I went on this webpage: http://www.scipy.org/install.html

And I realize I'd better to download Macports first. Therefore I went there http://www.macports.org/install.php and clicked on "Montain Lion" in "Mac OS X Package (.pkg) Installer"

Then I entered:

> sudo port install py27-numpy py27-scipy py27-matplotlib py27-ipython
>   +notebook py27-pandas py27-sympy py27-nose

in the terminal. I had to wait for more than 20 minutes but it seemed that everything worked fine.

When I go on Python Idle and write

> import scipy

I get

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       import scipy   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/**init**.py",
>   line 70, in 
>       from numpy import show_config as show_numpy_config ImportError: No module named numpy

Could you please help me with this issue?

Comment: `No module named numpy` -> Numpy isn't correctly installed. Try `import numpy` it should also throw an error. You can try to reinstall numpy.

Comment: @plg If I write "sudo port install py27-numpy" in the terminal it doesn't solve the problem. But indeed the problem comes frmo numpy who doesn't seem to be installed. What should I do?

Comment: Go to `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`. You should see a bunch of `.pth` files, open the numpy one in TextEdit (or whatever) and check if it actually points to numpy's installation.

Comment: @plg I don't have any `.pth` files! I only have one `README` file, one `vboxapi[something..]` file and a folder `vboxapi[something...]`. vboxapi is for virtual Box.

Comment: Macports must install them in another location then. The easiest way to get numpy would be compiling it yourself. Don't be afraid, this is actually really easy! Download the source from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/latest/download?source=files). Then `[sudo] python ~/Downloads/numpy-1.7.0/setup.py install` You might have to install a couple of packages from Macports to successfully build it, but that's not too complicated

Comment: @Awesome! THanks a lot @plg for your help! You can write your solution as an answer.

Comment: Not directly relevant but I would recommend using [homebrew](http://brew.sh) instead of macports to manage your python installation.

Answer (score 4):

Python is installed with Mac OS X so you could use easy_install

> sudo easy_install numpy

MacPorts installs python (and as it seems the eggs) to another location but you are using the Mac OS X python and so python can't find them.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken `easy_install` isn't pre-installed on OS X

Comment: It think it is. see [Python 3.2.3, easy_install, Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392699/python-3-2-3-easy-install-mac-os-x)

Comment: If you read the answer you could find this: `... the ones that come pre-installed with OS X ...`

Comment: Mea culpa, I had a memory of installing it on my system, but that probably was virtual_env.

Comment: Worked for me and solved the same problem! Awesome. (I was installing pypdf).

Comment: Worked for me without `sudo`. Perhaps make a note that `sudo` might not be required?