# How to install an "add-on" like Send2Trash to be used in Python?

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python programming and I am working on a project that I want to send files to the recycle bin using python. I heard of this "add-on" called Send2Trash which is what I wanted but I don't really know how to install it. I tried on the python website, other websites and from the author and it really didn't made any sense about the python setup.py install and  about "Distutils". Can someone help give a clear instruction on installing this type of "add-on" very clearly. And also I apologize if I ask something like this because I'm still a beginner in python but it is really a big help if someone can solve this problem.

Comment: There are installation instructions on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Send2Trash: `pip install Send2Trash`.

Comment: Duplicate of either http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449494/how-do-i-install-python-packages-on-windows , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605911/installing-python-packages-modules-on-mac or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034959/installing-python-modules-on-ubuntu (depending on operating system)

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer

If you are getting the error while using Python 3 on Mac OS X, try these commands in Terminal: `pip3 install Send2Trash` or `pip3 install send2trash`

I am on Mac OS X using Python 3, and this worked for me.

---

#### Explanation

I have read that most Mac OS X users have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed. Using `pip3` (instead of `pip`) installs the module on Python 3 (instead of Python 2). *(Disclaimer: I don't know if this explanation is correct.)*